# How to pass AWS credentials with the help of codedeploy scripts to an EC2 Server?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I have created an appspec.yml file to use it with aws codedeploy to deploy code to aws ec2 instance. Now in that instance I have to call aws secrets manager so that I can access my secrets. For this I have to install aws cli inside the ec2 server. Now the question is after installing aws cli how do I configure aws cli with the credentials securely. I do not like the approach to write a bash script which will configure credentials inside the server as it is very insecure. Any other methods possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would recomend to give the ec2 instance a IAM Role.
With the IAM-Role the Instance can access aws services without the need of credentials.

Check the offical documentation for implementation recomendations:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html

Comment: I have attached an IAM role to the EC2 instance to call secrets manager without configuring aws cli but still secrets manager wants "region name" to be specified in aws configuration. How can I cope up with this?

Comment: You could pass the region as a env variable: export AWS_REGION=your_aws_region